# If then how to use ReClass here without having to use a 1 gb padding?

Tags: memory, reverse-engineering, cheat-engine

So I'm currently a bit stuck in reversing the player structure of a game.

I found the health address on lets say

*address 1*

then i found the position and rotation on

address 1251864 (size 20: x, y, z, pitch, yaw)

and then the stamina on

addresss 5238234

The point I want to make is that it seems like the player structure is completely messed up. You won't find anything player related if you e.g browse the memory region around the health value.

**Why is that?** How would someone come up with a solid ReClass solution without having to use a 1 gb char padding in class?

Note: The game uses Denuvo but that shouldn't be the reason. Also the game is offline and does not feature an anti-cheat

I already tried to google but the results never really explained it.